# When using a tunneling service with Node.js, how do you get the actual URL from a request? (express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, protocols, tunnel

I've searched everywhere about this issue, but I can't seem to find any solution.

Say I use Express.js in Node, and I use localtunnel or serveo to tunnel it so anybody can access the site.

I want to perform a basic redirect to the encrypted site (https) when the client tries to access the http:// version.

I've tried this:

```js
const app = require("express")();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  if (req.protocol === "http") return res.redirect(302, req.protocol + "://" + req.headers.get("Host") + req.url);
  return res.send("Hello!");
});

app.listen(8080);

(async () => {
  const tunnel = await localtunnel({ port: 8080, subdomain: "example" });
  console.log(tunnel.url);
})();
```

But this leads to an infinite loop of redirects *no matter what*, since `req.protocol` is *always* `http`, because the request always returns the original URL (`http://localhost:8080`) and not the tunneled URL (`https://example.loca.lt`).

I've also tried getting the URL or referer from the request headers, but the only thing it returns is the hostname of the tunneled URL (`example.loca.lt`).

**Is there any way to get the tunnel URL's protocol from the client when requesting a page in Express.js?**

Comment: Have you tried the [`local-https` option](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel#options)?

Comment: @Bergi yep, but problem is I'm using serveo, not localtunnel, and when a request comes in, usually I can just use the "x-forwarded-proto" header to detect if the protocol is https or http. With serveo it's just plain and I can't do this.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with their proxy then. You should raise an issue in their bug tracker

Comment: @Bergi the repo is kind of dead, I'd doubt they'd notice. I guess there is no solution then. Localtunnel has an annoying blocker where you have to enter my public IP address to enter the site. Serveo's the only other tunneling service with https, free subdomains, and no annoying friendly reminder. Thanks for your help though!